# c# string.length

Tags: c#, string

This simple code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Check(string chosen_username, string email) {
        var lang = RouteData.Values["lang"]; ViewBag.Language = lang;

        string un; string em;
        try {
            un = chosen_username; em = email;
        }
        catch { un = ""; em = ""; }

        string s = un.Length.ToString();
        ViewBag.test = s;

        return View();
    }
```

Throws the object reference not set to an instance of an object-exception (on the line that reads "string s = un.Length.ToString();"

Could anybody help a C# newbie out please?

Comment: Have you checked if ViewBag is null?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you did not initialize ViewBag object or it is null.
Try this

```
if (ViewBag != null)
    ViewBag.test = un.Length.ToString();
```

To be sure that problem is not in string (and it's not, believe me) try this

```
string s = un.Length.ToString();
```

and use debugger to check that s is the one you expected.

**EDITED after OP posted new code:**
Simply: string un is null!!
Try using

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(un))
    ViewBag.test = un.Length.ToString();
else {
    // Manage here the error
}
```

Comment: Marco: The thing is, I've put something into my ViewBag just before. So viewbag shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: Marco: (cont'd): The same exception is thrown, if I try to Response.Write(un.Length.ToString()) - with or without the ToString()

Comment: @JesperNielsen: `un.Length.ToString()` works, so problem is elsewhere ;)

Comment: Please see the new code. I am still getting the same exception.

Comment: Yes, trying to write chosen_username shows that. I just don't see how that's possible, but that's another question. Will debug it thoroughly now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Object reference exception is referring to your `ViewBag` object, not your `un.Length.ToString()` value.

The following should run fine:

```
string un = "test"; string em = "test";
string test = un.Length.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

you should get that null pointer exception if chosen_username is null, since you never initialized your un string variable,

you should either:
- check for null input 
- initialize your function local variables
- assign them to avoid null as in :
**un = chosen_username ?? string.Empty;**